# Android Application with Database remote

Tags: java, android, web-services, jdbc

I am developing an application in which all information is stored in a remote database, all my applications have been with local data using SQLITE, I wonder what it is more feasible in relation to the performance of my CRUD application. 
Shaping my DAO to seek and record information using webservice and JSON as a response? or use JDBC?

Comment: I suggest using a webservice

Comment: remembering that not only must seek information also need to send information . (CRUD)

Comment: you can send information to a webservice